# My Apache module at my XAMPP is working under two PIDs. Is it fine?

Tags: php, xampp

My Apache module at my XAMPP is working under two PIDs. Is it fine?

One of my php code is now not running

Is it the problem in my code or xampp PIDs (but code was earlier running)?

Please help!!!

Comment: If you mean that the apache http server is executed in _two_ (or more) separate processes, then the answer is: that is normal in typical configurations. The server spawns a (configurable) number of child processes to be able to serve requests fast.

Comment: About the php script: sorry, we are good, but we are not _that_ good. We cannot _guess_ your script, your setup, your log files, ...

Comment: In other words, please provide your code, error messages etc so that we can help

Comment: Thanks guys I did lit bit research on Google and got the solution.

Thanks Again for your giving your valuble time.